# session for authenticated user is not being set

Tags: php, laravel, security, session

(I'm aware that the following example isn't safe)

I have a basic authentication system where a user has to enter his credentials. When the entered credentials are correct I set in my laravel application a session, which indicates that he can perform authenticated requests to the api. I do that the following way:

```
 public function authenticate(Request $request){
    $data = array(
        'name' => $request->input('UserName'),
        'password' =>$request->input('Password'),
        'email' => 'test@test.ch'
    );

    If(Auth::attempt($data)){
        $request->session()->put('isAuthenticated',true);
        $request->session()->save();
        return "success";
    }
    return "wrong";
}
```

My middleware where I check if the user is allowed to make requests:

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next){
    if(!empty($request->session()->get('isAuthenticated')) && $request->session()->get('isAuthenticated') === true){
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::post('/login', 'UserController@authenticate'); 

Route::group(['middleware' =>['web','check_auth']], function (){
Route::get('/logs','LogController@getAllLogEntries');
Route::get('/logs/{id}','LogController@getLogEntryById');
});
```

**My problem:**

Whenever a user logs in with the right credentials the server returns "success" as response, but always directs me back to the base root ('/'). That makes me assume that the session doesn't get set. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Which session driver you are use?

Comment: Can you please share your full `login` method instead of the snippet?

Comment: I'm using: 'use Illuminate\Http\Request' @AhmedAtoui

Comment: Have you started the session in every php file?

Comment: Check updated answer @IlGala

Comment: Thats the only place where I create my session @davidev

Comment: Have you checked with something like `dd($request->session()->get('isAuthenticated'))` what's stored when you run the middleware?

Comment: How can I view the output of dd(..) @IlGala

Comment: Straight in your browser... `dd` stands for "Die and Dump"...

Comment: it display "null" in my browser

Comment: And that's the problem... This means that `isAuthenticated` is null... There are 2 possible answers:

1) The middleware is running before the authentication process
2) The authentication process is somehow failing

Comment: I mean sesion driver (file - database - Redis..etc )?